# Is it possible in Swift to create initializer that takes a superclass object as an argument?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

For example, I have a simple subclass of UIImage that have some additional properties:

```
class Image: UIImage {

    var poeticDescription: String?

}
```

What I would like is like this:

```
init(with: UIImage) { /* something to do here */ }
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it out?

Comment: You don't want to subclass `UIImage`. You want to create a class that has a `UIImage` property in addition to other properties.

Comment: What about creating extension to `UIImage` and return in that function UIImage instance with modified properties?

Comment: Thank you, Dominik. I have considered that way. But I need UIImage instance with some additional properties. Extensions can't have stored properties, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize an existing object a second time, no matter, if the source object is a superclass object or not. Of course you can call the initializer with a superclass object as argument, but this will create a completely new object.

```
init(with superclassObject: SuperClass) {
    // Do some stuff with superclass object
}
```

The usual way to do inheriting is calling the superclass initializer in the inherited initializer:

```
init() {
    super.init()
}
```

But again, in this case you cannot use an already existing superclass object to initialize it again.

Maybe you can explain, what you want to achieve. We can then help you to find the correct way.

Comment: Yes, I can create that way an UIImage subclass initializer that takes filename. Or that takes Data. Or that takes CGImage object. But what if I already have an UIImage object (it might be a resizable image or even an animated one)? It seems, it is impossible, to take UIImage object 'as is' and create from it an UIImage subclass object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is to have a `UIImage` subclass with custom properties. You have to call a super initializer with the source image's data. For `UIImage` subclassing is tricky, have a look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47764163/5471218) for an example.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Basically the problem is, what if I don't know the source image's data, if I already have an UIImage object (it might be a resizable image or even an animated one), it seems, it is impossible (or very tricky), to take UIImage object 'as is' and create from it an UIImage subclass object. Well, now I think to create a wrapper class instead of subclass is an optimal way in the case.

Comment: @BenG +1 for using a wrapper instead of subclassing